# Luke - access my Lucene index in ram?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search, luke

How do I access my Lucene index with Luke when I have configured my hibernate search's directory provider as ram?

I don't know what to enter for path:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. A Lucene RAM index cannot be inspected with Luke. You need a file system based index. A RAM index is only visible within the JVM creating it and is lost on restart. It's main purpose is during development and test or in application where an index is only temporarily needed.